# What happens if you stay on the plane?

Tags: pubg-battlegrounds

I'm watching a few youtubers play PU-Battlegrounds, and I'm wondering... What happens if you never jump out of the airplane? What if you just ride it out and never leave?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are automatically ejected from the plane if you don't exit before it is about to leave the map. (Self source) So you cannot "never leave".

Also from [here](http://forums.playbattlegrounds.com/topic/1057-choosing-when-to-leave-plane/).

Comment: By the way, it's a great way to start with a few kills by killing the afk's :)

Comment: Are these kills worth anything at the end? I mean, they don't have any equip to loot and stuff. So it's just that you number of kills is higher at the end of the game?

Comment: Kills increase your BP earned at the end of a match and technically up your K/D